# Hierarchical Factor Analysis in R using FactoMineR

Tags: r, factor-analysis

I'm new to R - moved from SAS and I'm just not sure on the syntax.

I'm working on a dataset with one hundred patients examined at 4 different time points using eighty variables at each time point.

I've been using FactoMineR as hypothesis generation and done a PCA and MFA on the first examination, but I want to include all the data in my analysis.

I see two options:

1. MFA:
   See: https://groups.google.com/g/factominer-users/c/6T3QD-aRtmY
   This functions plot module includes a chrono option. When TRUE it will connect the partial points of the same variables.
   My current data is in seperate dataframes as:
   Visit 1:
   |row |   var 1  | Var 2  | Var 3|
   |:---|:--------:|:------:|-----:|
   |1   | a        |  aa    | aaa  |
   |2   | b        |  bb    | bbb  |
   |3   | c        |  cc    | ccc  |

Visit 2:

In order to do this my data should be:
| ..       | ..    | Visit 1|  ..     |  ..    |Visit2  |        |
|:-------|:-----:|:------:|:-------:|:---------------:|-------:|
|rownames| Var1  |  Var2  |   Var 3 |  Var1  |  Var2  |  Var3  |
1    | a     |   b    |    c    |   aa   |  bb    |  cc    |

I've trouble displaing the table the correct way. Please see the link also.

How do i set this up so that the MFA recognizes the repeated variables as nested within each visit?
My current code is:

```
res.mfa <- MFA (tt.a, 
                group = c(1, 1, 9, 4, 4, 6, 10, 3, 3, 5, 10), 
                type = c("s", "n", "s", "s", "s", "s", "s", "s", "n", "n", "s"), 
                name.group = c("age", "xxx", "......"),
                num.group.sup = c(1,2), 
                ncp = nbdimFAMD$ncp,
                graph = F)
```

2. HMFA
   This could be used as defining each visit as a top level in a hierachy.
   But comming from SAS I simply just don't get the code in the vignettes example:

```
data(wine)
hierar <- list(c(2,5,3,10,9,2), c(4,2))
res.hmfa <- HMFA(wine, H = hierar, type=c("n",rep("s",5)))
```

I've run it in my console and it works perfectly. The interpretation however is difficult.
But specifically - I dont understand what the list functions does and hence I can't create a hierachy on my own dataset.
Do I create a list from each visit and then combine them in one dataframe?

It may be simple but new to the syntax and I'm still learning.

I hope you can help!

Kind regards